# Trying Decorator Design Pattern, what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns

I have this code that explains the decorator pattern:

```
 public abstract class IBeverage {
    protected string description = "Unknown beverage";

    public virtual string getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}

public abstract class CondimentDecorator : IBeverage {
    public abstract string getDescription();
}

public class Espresso : IBeverage {
    public Espresso() {
        description = "Espresso";
    }
}

public class Mocha : CondimentDecorator {
    IBeverage beverage;

    public Mocha(IBeverage beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public override string getDescription() {
        return beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }
}
```

I should use it like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    IBeverage b = new Espresso();
    Console.WriteLine(b.getDescription());
    b = new Mocha(b);
    Console.WriteLine(b.getDescription());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I create the beverage (Beverage b = new Espresso();) _description is updated to "Espresso", when I decorate b with Mocha (b = new Mocha(b)), then _description takes the original value "Unknown Beverage". It should be "Espresso, Mocha". **What's wrong?**

This code was originally written in Java (the book was written with Java), but I translated it into C#. I guess Java works a little different from C#.

Comment: your example code looks not quite right. Your class is called `IBeverage` but in Main you create a `Beverage`, and is it just one `GetDescription` or two different description methods? (one is lowercase g and the other uppercase g).

Comment: I recommend you drop the abstract CondimentDecorator class, change IBeverage to an actual interface, and have Mocha implement IBeverage.

Comment: I think this is based on the Head First Design Pattern book. They have both classes, but the IBeverage class (naming conventions aside) also needs to be abstract.

Comment: I edited the example to the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've actually got a few issues here (perhaps differing designs from Java). Even after sorting all of the naming issues, you will not get what you expect.

```
public abstract class CondimentDecorator : IBeverage {
    public abstract string GetDescription();
}
```

- The `CondimentDecorator` class will actually hide the `IBeverage` version `GetDescription()` method (you technically should use `public new abstract string GetDescription();`.
- You are classifying the `Mocha` class as an `IBeverage` by assigning it to the `b` variable (which you earlier defined as an IBeverage via  `IBeverage b = new Espresso()`, the `IBeverage` version of the `GetDescription()` method is what actually fires (totally ignoring the `Mocha` override of the `CondimentDecorator` `GetDescription()` method)

You can see this if you step through the code. Try using

```
CondimentDecorator m = new Mocha(b);
Console.WriteLine(m.GetDescription());
```

and you will get what you expect.

However, this kind of defeats the purpose of using a decorator in my opinion. A better option would be to change the design a bit and get rid of the CondimentDecorator. It is not providing anything other than confusion and unexpected behaviour. Instead try this:

This is your only needed abstract Beverage class:

```
public abstract class Beverage
{
    // c# convention is to use properties instead of public fields.
    // In this case I've used a private readonly backing field. 
    private readonly string _description = "Unknown Beverage";

    protected string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }

    // Make this method virtual so you can override it, but if you
    // choose not to, this is the default behaviour.
    public virtual string GetDescription()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}
```

This is a standard beverage class (can be decorated):

```
public class Espresso : Beverage
{
    public Espresso()
    {
        // Setting the Beverage class Description property.
        // You can use base.Description if you prefer to be explicit
        Description = "Espresso";
    }
}
```

This is a Beverage class that decorates another Beverage class:

```
public class Mocha : Beverage
{
    // store an instance of the Beverage class to be decorated
    private readonly Beverage _beverage;

    // Beverage instance to be decorated is passed in via constructor
    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
    {
        _beverage = beverage;
    }

    // Override Beverage.GetDescription
    public override string GetDescription()
    {
        // Calls decorated Beverage's GetDescription and appends to it.
        return _beverage.GetDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }
}
```

And now to get the behaviour you expect, you can run the same code as above:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Beverage b = new Espresso();
    Console.WriteLine(b.getDescription()); // "Espresso"
    b = new Mocha(b);
    Console.WriteLine(b.getDescription()); // "Espresso, Mocha"

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

*As a side note. You can avoid using* `Console.ReadKey();` *when debugging by using* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> *This will automatically put in `"Press any key to continue..."` for you.*

**UPDATE**

Since you want to include the CondimentDecorator class (as mentioned in your comment), you can create the following class:

```
public abstract class CondimentDecorator : Beverage
{
    private readonly Beverage _beverage;

    protected Beverage Bevy
    {
        get { return _beverage; }
    }

    protected CondimentDecorator(Beverage beverage)
    {
        _beverage = beverage;
    }
}
```

Then you would change your `Mocha` class to the following:

```
// override CondimentDecorator instead of Beverage
public class Mocha : CondimentDecorator
{
    // Pass the Beverage to be decorated to the base constructor
    // (CondimentDecorator)
    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
        : base(beverage)
    {
        // nothing needed in this constructor
    }

    public override string GetDescription()
    {
        // Now access the CondimentDecorator's Beverage property 
        // (which I called Bevy to differentiate it)
        return Bevy.GetDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Jason, I tried what you suggested but didn't get the right result. I think that the problem is that the now private backing field _description is actually taking the original value set in the abstract base class IBeverage (previously Beverage), the no matter if the method is hidden or not, the value is not right

Comment: I tried running the code here and got the expected results. Are you sure you tried what I listed above exactly? It is important that you get rid of the CondimentDecorator class. Having one class declare an abstract method with the same signature as the class it is derived from will cause the hiding issue I mentioned.

Comment: You were right, it worked!!, but what if I wanted to keep using this CondimentDecorator, Mocha is not an actual beverage!!, i'd like tostablish the fact that it is just a flavor.

Comment: I found a solution, I keep the CondimentDecorator, but it doesn't have the abstract method GetDescription. And all the decorators must derive from it.

Comment: You are correct. And you can move the Beverage constructor parameter from Mocha into the CondimentDecorator and expose the Beverage being decorated in a property. I'll update my example.

Answer (score 4):

Because `GetDescription()` is not `virtual`.

```
public virtual string GetDescription() { ... }
```

`virtual` is the companion keyword to `override`, it's what allows subclasses to override methods. This is a key difference in C# from Java. In Java all methods are implicitly virtual.

Comment: GetDescription is not the method that's being overridden. Mocha is overriding getDescription from the abstract class. Edit: Nevermind, I see now that there are simply typos in the write-up code.

Comment: @FacioRatio That is true, but if you look at his code, he is calling `getBeverage` against an `IBeverage`, which does not have that method. I think he meant all the methods to have a capital G.

Comment: Yes I just realized that. :)

Comment: Actually, against a `Beverage`, which doesn't exist :) OP's example could use some work.

Comment: I updated the code and set GetBeverage to virtual, but it still doesn't work.
Sorry if the were some errors with Beverage and IBeverage.
The problem is not with the GetDescription method, the variable _description it's taking the value of the abstract class when applying the decorator.